# User management with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm having some trouble with Node.JS. I don't understand how to delete a user from MongoDB. Actually, I use rest API to send a DELETE request with userId as parameter, however, it delete the current user (administrator...) instead of target user. I think i'm forgetting something but I don't know what. Here is my code (I've use Angular Passport to start my project https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport)

Backend:

routes.js

```
var users = require('../controllers/users');
  app.post('/auth/users', auth.ensureAuthenticated, auth.ensureAdministrator, users.create);
  app.get('/auth/users/:userId', auth.ensureAuthenticated, users.show);
  app.get('/auth/users', auth.ensureAuthenticated, auth.ensureAdministrator, users.all);
  app.del('/auth/users/:userId', auth.ensureAuthenticated, auth.ensureAdministrator, users.destroy);
```

controllers/users.js

```
/**
 * Delete a user
 */
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
  var user = req.user;
  user.delete(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.send();
    }
  });
};
```

Frontend:

app.js

```
.when('/users/:userId/delete', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/delete_user.html',
        controller: 'UsersCtrl'
      })
```

services/user.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularPassportApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('auth/users/:userId', {
      userId: '@_id'
    }, 
      {
        'update': {
          method:'PUT'
        },
         'destroy': {
          method:'DELETE'
          }
      }); 
  });
```

controllers/users.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularPassportApp')
  .controller('UsersCtrl', function ($scope, User, Auth, $location, $routeParams, $rootScope) {

    $scope.remove = function() {
      var user = $scope.user;
      user.$remove();

      for (var i in $scope.users) {
        if ($scope.users[i] == user) {
          $scope.users.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }

      $location.path('/');
    };

    $scope.findOne = function() {
      User.get({ 
        userId: $routeParams.userId
      },function(user) {
        $scope.user = user;
        console.log(user);
      });
    };

  });
```

Html :

```
<section ng-init="findOne()">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Delete this user ?</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="remove()">
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <p>Do you really want to delete this user ?</p>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your Node endpoint in exports.destroy.

You need to pass the user ID to the collection of users.

```
MyModel.remove({search: criteria}, function() {
    // removed.
});
```